# Duplicate directory error on rails, after installing elixir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elixir, ruby-on-rails-5, elixir-mix

1. I have read the [relevant entry](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors) on github:guard/listen
2. I am able to reproduce this error consistently after a fresh boot (restart)

I was working on a ruby on rails project, and was able to serve the site locally with no errors. After compiling elixir, and serving an elixir site locally (but no concurrently with rails), I run into a duplicate directory error whenever I try to serve the rails site locally.

Overall, I am still able to serve the rails project and use the site. But the errors are an eyesore, and I don't think it's healthy to ignore them.

**Error Message**

```
$ bin/rails server
... (more errors)
** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **

        Directory: /home/ning/github/cadet/_build/dev/lib/jose/include

        is already being watched through: /home/ning/github/cadet/deps/jose/include

        MORE INFO: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors
** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **

        Directory: /home/ning/github/elixir-1.6.0/lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test compiles and cleans src/b.erl and src/c.erl/_build/dev/lib/sample/include

        is already being watched through: /home/ning/github/elixir-1.6.0/lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test compiles and cleans src/b.erl and src/c.erl/include

        MORE INFO: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors
... (more errors)
```

The first directory (cadet) is the elixir project which I had served locally, but not concurrently with this rails project. The second is the elixir repository, with which I compiled elixir.

**Directory Structure**

```
.
├── cadet
├── cvwo-assignment
├── ... (other dirs)
└── elixir-1.6.0
```

**Finding symlinks**

I understand that recursive symlinks may generate this error. I don't think I have any of those, as far as I can tell.

In the rails project (cvwo-assignment),

```
$ find . -type l -ls
$
```

In the elixir repository (elixir-1.6.0),

```
$ find . -type l -ls
  2359425      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           31 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/applies\ variables\ from\ system_env\ for\ rebar3/_build/dev/lib/git_rebar/ebin -> ../../../../deps/git_rebar/ebin
  2359430      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           29 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/applies\ variables\ from\ system_env\ for\ rebar3/_build/dev/lib/rebar_dep/ebin -> ../../../../../rebar_dep/ebin
  1574346      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.ArchiveTest/test\ archive\ build/_build/dev/lib/archive/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1574212      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.ArchiveTest/test\ archive\ check/_build/dev/lib/archive/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1574378      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.ArchiveTest/test\ archive\ checksum/_build/dev/lib/archive/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1574442      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.ArchiveTest/test\ archive\ build\ with\ include-dot-files/_build/dev/lib/archive/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1574410      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.ArchiveTest/test\ archive\ update/_build/dev/lib/archive/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1574244      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.ArchiveTest/test\ archive\ install/_build/dev/lib/archive/priv -> ../../../../priv
  2359848      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.ProjectTest/test\ builds\ the\ project\ structure/_build/archive/priv -> ../../priv
  2359833      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           13 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.ProjectTest/test\ builds\ the\ project\ structure\ with\ symlinks/_build/archive/include -> ../../include
  2359834      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.ProjectTest/test\ builds\ the\ project\ structure\ with\ symlinks/_build/archive/priv -> ../../priv
  2359500      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           31 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/get\ and\ compile\ dependencies\ for\ Rebar/_build/dev/lib/git_rebar/ebin -> ../../../../deps/git_rebar/ebin
  2359505      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           29 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/get\ and\ compile\ dependencies\ for\ Rebar/_build/dev/lib/rebar_dep/ebin -> ../../../../../rebar_dep/ebin
   920418      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           24 Jan 20 09:48 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.DepsTest/test\ checks\ list\ of\ dependencies\ and\ their\ status\ with\ success/_build/dev/lib/ok/priv -> ../../../../deps/ok/priv
 11930769      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           24 Jan 20 09:48 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.DepsTest/test\ checks\ if\ dependencies\ are\ using\ old\ Elixir\ version/_build/dev/lib/ok/priv -> ../../../../deps/ok/priv
   920365      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           24 Jan 20 09:48 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.DepsTest/test\ checks\ if\ dependencies\ are\ using\ old\ scm\ version/_build/dev/lib/ok/priv -> ../../../../deps/ok/priv
   920495      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           24 Jan 20 09:48 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.DepsTest/test\ prints\ Elixir\ req\ mismatches/_build/dev/lib/ok/priv -> ../../../../deps/ok/priv
  2359654      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           31 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/applies\ variables\ from\ system_env\ for\ Rebar/_build/dev/lib/git_rebar/ebin -> ../../../../deps/git_rebar/ebin
  2359658      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           44 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/applies\ variables\ from\ system_env\ for\ Rebar/_build/dev/lib/rebar_dep/ebin -> ../../../../../rebar_dep/apps/rebar_dep/ebin
  1573989      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test\ compilation\ purges\ the\ module/_build/dev/lib/sample/include -> ../../../../include
  1573910      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test\ saves\ warnings\ between\ builds/_build/dev/lib/sample/include -> ../../../../include
  1574008      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test\ compiles\ and\ cleans\ src/b.erl\ and\ src/c.erl/_build/dev/lib/sample/include -> ../../../../include
  1573972      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test\ continues\ even\ if\ one\ file\ fails\ to\ compile/_build/dev/lib/sample/include -> ../../../../include
  1573927      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test\ removes\ old\ artifact\ files/_build/dev/lib/sample/include -> ../../../../include
  1573941      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test\ raises\ on\ invalid\ erlc_options/_build/dev/lib/sample/include -> ../../../../include
  1573954      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ErlangTest/test\ prints\ warnings\ from\ stale\ files\ with\ --all-warnings/_build/dev/lib/sample/include -> ../../../../include
  1442933      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ escript\ install\ and\ uninstall/_build/dev/lib/escript_test/priv -> ../../../../priv
 11281725      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ escript\ invalid\ main\ module/_build/dev/lib/escript_test_with_unknown_main_module/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1442754      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ Erlang\ and\ deps/_build/dev/lib/escript_test_erlang_with_deps/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1442750      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           59 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ Erlang\ and\ deps/_build/dev/lib/ok/priv -> ../../../../../../../test/fixtures/deps_status/deps/ok/priv
 11930801      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ config/_build/dev/lib/escript_test/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1442970      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ deps/_build/dev/lib/escript_test_with_deps/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1442966      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           59 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ deps/_build/dev/lib/ok/priv -> ../../../../../../../test/fixtures/deps_status/deps/ok/priv
  1442718      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ debug\ information/_build/dev/lib/escript_test_with_debug_info/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1442866      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ path/_build/dev/lib/escript_test_with_path/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1443045      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript\ with\ --no-compile\ flag/_build/dev/lib/escript_test/priv -> ../../../../priv
  1442900      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           16 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.Tasks.EscriptTest/test\ generate\ escript/_build/dev/lib/escript_test/priv -> ../../../../priv
 12062101      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.UtilsTest/test\ symlink\ or\ copy\ erases\ wrong\ symlinks/_build/archive/ebin -> ../../ebin
   661399      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           10 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/Mix.UtilsTest/test\ symlink\ or\ copy/_build/archive/ebin -> ../../ebin
  2359582      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           31 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/get\ and\ compile\ dependencies\ for\ rebar3/_build/dev/lib/git_rebar/ebin -> ../../../../deps/git_rebar/ebin
  2359587      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           29 Jan 20 09:49 ./lib/mix/tmp/get\ and\ compile\ dependencies\ for\ rebar3/_build/dev/lib/rebar_dep/ebin -> ../../../../../rebar_dep/ebin
$
```

In the elixir project (cadet),

```
$ find . -type l -ls
 10641466      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           29 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/phoenix/priv -> ../../../../deps/phoenix/priv
  8279908      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           31 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/base64url/ebin -> ../../../../deps/base64url/ebin
  9971625      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           33 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/file_system/priv -> ../../../../deps/file_system/priv
  7877030      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           16 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/cadet/priv -> ../../../../priv
 10641595      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           41 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/phoenix_live_reload/priv -> ../../../../deps/phoenix_live_reload/priv
  9971681      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           41 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/unicode_util_compat/ebin -> ../../../../deps/unicode_util_compat/ebin
 10104506      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           31 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/cowlib/include -> ../../../../deps/cowlib/include
 10104505      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           28 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/cowlib/ebin -> ../../../../deps/cowlib/ebin
 10103044      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           30 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/comeonin/priv -> ../../../../deps/comeonin/priv
 10102978      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           29 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/poolboy/ebin -> ../../../../deps/poolboy/ebin
 10641336      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           28 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/cowboy/ebin -> ../../../../deps/cowboy/ebin
 10103177      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           27 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/timex/priv -> ../../../../deps/timex/priv
 10103087      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           36 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/ssl_verify_fun/ebin -> ../../../../deps/ssl_verify_fun/ebin
 10103151      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           28 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/tzdata/priv -> ../../../../deps/tzdata/priv
  9971618      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           28 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/mimerl/ebin -> ../../../../deps/mimerl/ebin
 10103144      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           32 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/hackney/include -> ../../../../deps/hackney/include
 10103143      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           29 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/hackney/ebin -> ../../../../deps/hackney/ebin
  9971671      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           29 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/metrics/ebin -> ../../../../deps/metrics/ebin
 10641869      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           32 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/ex_machina/priv -> ../../../../deps/ex_machina/priv
 10103109      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           29 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/certifi/ebin -> ../../../../deps/certifi/ebin
 10641437      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           34 Jan 20 14:28 ./_build/dev/lib/phoenix_html/priv -> ../../../../deps/phoenix_html/priv
  9971698      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           26 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/idna/ebin -> ../../../../deps/idna/ebin
  9971749      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           29 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/jose/include -> ../../../../deps/jose/include
  9971750      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           26 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/jose/priv -> ../../../../deps/jose/priv
 10102901      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           27 Jan 20 14:27 ./_build/dev/lib/ranch/ebin -> ../../../../deps/ranch/ebin
  3021153      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           22 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/redent/node_modules/.bin/strip-indent -> ../strip-indent/cli.js
  8028969      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           18 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/phoenix -> ../../deps/phoenix
  3021149      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           20 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/.bin/semver -> ../semver/bin/semver
  3021159      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/svgo/node_modules/.bin/js-yaml -> ../js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js
  3021157      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/svgo/node_modules/.bin/esparse -> ../esprima/bin/esparse.js
  3021158      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           28 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/svgo/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate -> ../esprima/bin/esvalidate.js
  3021151      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           22 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/postcss-merge-rules/node_modules/.bin/browserslist -> ../browserslist/cli.js
  3021155      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           16 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/request/node_modules/.bin/uuid -> ../uuid/bin/uuid
  9840467      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/webpack-parallel-uglify-plugin/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs -> ../uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
  9582649      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           18 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/.bin/acorn -> ../acorn/bin/acorn
  3021145      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           22 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/caniuse-api/node_modules/.bin/browserslist -> ../browserslist/cli.js
  3021147      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           22 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/.bin/browserslist -> ../browserslist/cli.js
  8028970      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           23 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/phoenix_html -> ../../deps/phoenix_html
  3021143      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           18 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/babel-generator/node_modules/.bin/jsesc -> ../jsesc/bin/jsesc
  3021161      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs -> ../uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs
 8028999      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           16 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/csso -> ../csso/bin/csso
  8028991      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           19 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/nopt -> ../nopt/bin/nopt.js
  8029011      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           27 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp -> ../node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
  8029008      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           24 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/npm-path -> ../npm-path/bin/npm-path
  8029006      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           16 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/svgo -> ../svgo/bin/svgo
  8029020      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           26 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/tsserver -> ../typescript/bin/tsserver
  8029018      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           20 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/tslint -> ../tslint/bin/tslint
  8028009      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           26 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/ansi-html -> ../ansi-html/bin/ansi-html
  8028983      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           31 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/not-in-publish -> ../in-publish/not-in-publish.js
  8029005      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           21 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/internal-ip -> ../internal-ip/cli.js
  8029000      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           23 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/multicast-dns -> ../multicast-dns/cli.js
  8029004      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs -> ../uglify-es/bin/uglifyjs
  8028998      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/js-yaml -> ../js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js
  8028987      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           22 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/loose-envify -> ../loose-envify/cli.js
  8029015      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           27 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/prettier -> ../prettier/bin/prettier.js
  8029009      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           29 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/npm-which -> ../npm-which/bin/npm-which.js
  8028988      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           32 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/miller-rabin -> ../miller-rabin/bin/miller-rabin
  8029003      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           23 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/sshpk-sign -> ../sshpk/bin/sshpk-sign
  8028995      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           14 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/rgb -> ../rgb/bin/rgb
  8028979      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/esparse -> ../esprima/bin/esparse.js
  8029012      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           27 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/sassgraph -> ../sass-graph/bin/sassgraph
  8029001      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           23 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/sshpk-conv -> ../sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv
  8028990      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           20 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp -> ../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
  8029017      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           23 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/_ts-node -> ../ts-node/dist/_bin.js
  8028980      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           28 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate -> ../esprima/bin/esvalidate.js
  8028976      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/babylon -> ../babylon/bin/babylon.js
  8028981      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           27 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/in-publish -> ../in-publish/in-publish.js
  8029019      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           21 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/tsc -> ../typescript/bin/tsc
  8028977      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           20 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/cssesc -> ../cssesc/bin/cssesc
  8028985      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           18 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/jsesc -> ../jsesc/bin/jsesc
  8028992      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           15 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/errno -> ../errno/cli.js
  8028989      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           14 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/mime -> ../mime/cli.js
  8029013      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           23 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/lint-staged -> ../lint-staged/index.js
  8028996      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           20 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/semver -> ../semver/bin/semver
  8029014      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           26 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/node-sass -> ../node-sass/bin/node-sass
  8028982      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           27 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/in-install -> ../in-publish/in-install.js
  8029010      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           16 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/rimraf -> ../rimraf/bin.js
  8028008      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           18 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/acorn -> ../acorn/bin/acorn
  8028997      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           16 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/sha.js -> ../sha.js/bin.js
  8028993      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/regjsparser -> ../regjsparser/bin/parser
  8028984      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           31 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/not-in-install -> ../in-publish/not-in-install.js
  8029022      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           47 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server -> ../webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
  8029002      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/sshpk-verify -> ../sshpk/bin/sshpk-verify
  8028986      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           19 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/json5 -> ../json5/lib/cli.js
  8029016      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           22 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/ts-node -> ../ts-node/dist/bin.js
  8029007      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           18 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/which -> ../which/bin/which
  8028994      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           31 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/import-local-fixture -> ../import-local/fixtures/cli.js
  8029021      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           25 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/webpack -> ../webpack/bin/webpack.js
  8028978      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           22 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/browserslist -> ../browserslist/cli.js
  8028055      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 ning     ning           19 Jan 20 14:50 ./frontend/node_modules/.bin/atob -> ../atob/bin/atob.js
$
```

While there are quite a number of symlinks in the elixir repository and the elixir project directory, I don't any potentially recursive ones. And since the rails project itself does not contain any symlinks, I don't see why running `bin/rails serve` in that symlink-less project can result in 'symlink-recursion'.

**Versions**

The rails project is vanilla with no additional gems. I was told that the elixir project uses a framework called phoenix.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ rails --version
Rails 5.1.4
$ iex --version
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

IEx 1.6.0 (compiled with OTP 19)
$ mix --version
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Mix 1.6.0 (compiled with OTP 19)
```

Comment: Why for God’s sake would you have elixir sources under rails root directory?

Comment: @mudasobwa They are in separate directories. But I keep all my projects in a 'github' directory.